# PHP remove special character from string and leave some

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to remove all special characters from string except `- (  )`

I have this code so far

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $q); //removes ALL characters
```

how to exclude `- ( )` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try something like

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\(\) ]/', '', $q); //removes ALL characters
```

The above will allow `spaces`, `(`, `)` as well as `-`.

Answer (score 6):

Your regex is already excluding `-`.

Otherwise, put the brackets in the negated character class:

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9() -]/', '', $q);
```

Also, you don't need to escape the dash.

Comment: Okey its wowks, but it seems removes spaces too. How can we exclude space?

Comment: @MindaugasMilius Keeping spaces is a requirment as well? Oh, I didn't know. Just put a space within the square brackets, preferably before the dash: `/[^A-Za-z0-9() -]/`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this function:

```
public function getAlphaNumericString($string) {
  return  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\- ]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever you wanna make exception of
example => . is exception other special characters will be removed
 preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/(.)', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

```php
function url($string)
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
}


$url_name = 'manoj&chauhan';

echo =$url(url_name );

// result manoj-chauhan
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: i replace all speical character in url with this code...i'm not asking any question

Comment: They don't want to replace special char with `-`, reread the question.